Selenium "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)
I am running tens Firefox browsers with help of selenium python. My program was working fine, but now I see error in .screenshot() function
File "/project/parser_app/celery_tasks.py", line 225, in check_urls
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m     parser.check_parsing_result(parsing_results)
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m   File "/project/parser_app/parser/common.py", line 232, in check_parsing_result
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m     body_elem.screenshot(image_path)
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 725, in screenshot
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m     png = self.screenshot_as_png
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 705, in screenshot_as_png
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m     return b64decode(self.screenshot_as_base64.encode('ascii'))
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 693, in screenshot_as_base64
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m     return self._execute(Command.ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT)['value']
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 773, in _execute
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m     return self._parent.execute(command, params)
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
ESC[33mcelery_1_ef434aaf6a41 |ESC[0m selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: [Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://remote/cont
ent/shared/Capture.sys.mjs :: capture.canvas :: line 137"  data: no]

My function code
def check_parsing_result(self, parsing_results: List[ParsingResult]) -> None:
        """
        Check for pirated content on the page
        :param parsing_res: list of objects with url of the parsing result page
        """
        ...
            if os.getenv("SAVE_SCREENSHOT", 0):
                curr_time: str = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
                file_name = f"scrin_{curr_time}.png"
                image_path = f"{MEDIA_ROOT}/{file_name}"
                body_elem = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
                body_elem.screenshot(image_path)


I was checking free space in home directo:
df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 3.2G   43M  3.2G   2% /run
/dev/mapper/vg0-root   30G  6.0G   23G  22% /
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                  16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg1-var    69G   28G   39G  42% /var
/dev/loop0             12M   12M     0 100% /snap/ngrok/50
/dev/loop1             56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2823
/dev/loop2             56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2846
/dev/loop3             56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2829
/dev/loop4            6.9M  6.9M     0 100% /snap/ngrok/118
tmpfs                 3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1008

Example of web-page I am working with https://hdf3im.lordfilm1.pics/5587-0106-temnyj-rycar-2008.html
How to fix the error?

This question is similar to: WebDriverException: Message: Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" while saving a large html file using Selenium Python. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
